Boyce-Codd Normal Form in database
I have a question that appeared in exam and I wasn't able to solve it:
Consider the relation R(A,B,C,D) and the following set of FD's that hold over R

F = {AB->C, AC->B, BC->AD}

Is R in BCNF? If not, which FDs make R violate BCNF?

A. No, BC -> AD
B. No, AC -> B
C. Yes
D. No, AB -> C

What would be the right answer for this?
I tried to solve it by the theory:
To determine if the relation R(A,B,C,D) is in BCNF (Boyce-Codd Normal Form) given the functional dependencies (FDs) F = {AB->C, AC->B, BC->AD}, we need to check if each FD violates the condition of BCNF.
A functional dependency X -> Y violates BCNF if:
X is not a superkey for R.
Y is not a prime attribute (i.e., it is not part of any candidate key).
However, I wasn't able to arrive at any answer using the above concept.

You might get a better answer on the DBA Stack Exchange.
